# Sharepoint 2013 - Add lookup column to key filters

Tags: document-library, lookup-column, metadata

I've got a document library of invoices. It has various columns (mainly choices) such as, Year, Status, Location, etc. and I've been able to add them to metadata navigation as key filters.

However, I have one column Vendors which is a lookup column to another list. This list will be used elsewhere in the site for other document libraries. I am unable to use that column as a key filter. Are there any work arounds? Is this something I should use a Term Store for?

PS: I attempted to use the key filters to filter by Year first, and then use the dropdown menu in the column header to filter by Vendor and it still wouldn't work. Key filters override everything.

Answer (score 0):

Let's answer this old question in the context of SharePoint 2013.

Limitations of Metadata Navigation (Key Filters) exist :-/ ([Microsoft Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-c222a75d-8b18-44e2-9ed8-7ee4e0d23cfc)) Here is the extract:

> The following list shows the column types that the Key Filters control can use as fields:
>
> - Managed Metadata
> - Content Type
> - Choice
> - Person or Group
> - Date and Time
> - Number

In my experience Mixing Key Filter Navigation and column header filtering doesn't work. (I can't retrieve official reference from Microsoft)

Defining column "Vendor" with column type as "Managed Metadata" is likely a good alterative. The Managed Metadata could be defined in the global term store or in the site collection termstore depending the visibility you want for that metadata.